# Why does this code repeat?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments

This is code I've written for a class assignment. The assignment reads as follows:

"Build a function that will start the program. Please call it **main()**.
From the main() function, call a function called **getValue()**.
The getValue() function will get a number from the user that will be used for the next step.
Also from the main() function, call a function called **getSquareRoot()**.
The **getSquareRoot()** function will get the square root of the number that was received by the user in the **getValue()** function.
Make sure that you display the results, including the original number and the square root of the number, to the user in an **easily readable statement**.

Bolding is included in the original, by the way.

Here's my code **and it works, except** that somehow functions are being called twice, and results are being displayed twice, with the second iteration assigning userInput a value of 0. I can't seem to identify where the 'loop' is getting fired off (beginner here). Any help would be very much appreciated; I know I'n staring at it but it's totally eluding me.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Project 3 Part A</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">      

    <script>

        function main()
        {

            var msg1="";
            var msg2="";                
            var userInput = "";

            getValue(userInput);
            getSquareRoot(userInput);

        }

        function getValue(userInput)
        {

            var userInput = document.getElementById("userNumber").value;
            return getSquareRoot(userInput);

        }

        function getSquareRoot(userInput)           
        {           

            squareRoot = Math.sqrt(userInput);  
            var msg1 = "Your original number was " + userInput + ".";   
            var msg2 = "The square root of " + userInput + " is " + squareRoot + ".";   
            document.getElementById("original").innerHTML += msg1;
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += msg2;

        }




    </script>

</head>

<body>

        <br>

    <input type="button" id="userInputButton" onclick="javascript:main();" value="Square root input value: "/>          

    <input type="text" id="userNumber"> 

    </div>

    <div id="original">

    </div>

    <div id="results">

    </div>                      

</body>
```

enter code here

Comment: getSquareRoot is being called from main as well as getValue. Remove from either and its all good

Comment: getValue should have no arguments, you need to assign that to the variable in main, also do all the output in the main, it may work like it is, but it's not how it's usually done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that each function should optimally have 1 purpose only. The function 'getSquaredRoot' here is in charge of both calculating the root as well as outputting the result for the user to see.

Plus as Lucky Chingi said, you're calling getSquaredRoot twice.

```
       function main()
    {
        var userInput = getValue();        
        var squaredRoot = getSquareRoot(userInput);

        var msg1 = "Your original number was " + userInput + ".";   
        var msg2 = "The square root of " + userInput + " is " + squareRoot + ".";   
        document.getElementById("original").innerHTML += msg1;
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += msg2;

    }

    function getValue()
    {
        return document.getElementById("userNumber").value;
    }

    function getSquareRoot(userInput)           
    {           
        return Math.sqrt(userInput);  
    }
```

Notice how it's logically seperated now.

Comment: Aha! I was wondering while I was doing the assignment if I should also be calling a result()  function, but didn't because the assignment didn't explicitly say I could do so and tied myself I'm a logic knot. And, remembering one function should MEAN "one _function_" will help quite a bit, natch. Thanks!